# Ajax load dynamic page

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic, load

HTML index.php

```
<a class="cart-icon" href="cart"></a>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Ajax load content from load-content/cart.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.cart-icon', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var page = $(this).attr("href");
       $('.content').load('load-content/'+page+'.php');
   });
});
```

This code will load content from cart.php but not update a url so when i refresh the page the content in that div dissapear. I want it when i refresh page it will not dissapear and also update url.

For example:
default url: index.php and when i press an a tag it will load content from cart.php and update url to index.php/load-content/cart.php

Answer (score 1):

You need a persistent storage of *some* kind. Anything you load into the DOM of a page is temporary.
You might simply do the same thing that you're doing here on document load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.content').load('load-content/'+page+'.php');
   $(document).on('click', '.cart-icon', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var page = $(this).attr("href");
       $('.content').load('load-content/'+page+'.php');
   });
});
```

Comment: Oh i'm sorry that i explain complicated but i do not want the div load content before i'm clicking to the link, i just need update url and after that load the content when i'm clicking to the link also when i go back it will load previous page.

Comment: But it can't. You _always_ need to store your content somewhere. I just gave you one example but there are a lot of ways to do the store. Unless you store the data somewhere (and it's already stored in the page you're doing the `.load()` from), when you refresh the page it _must_ load the original page. When you do the refresh, there _must_ be something executed in the `.ready()` that loads the new content.